# Dynamically insert code before compilation in C

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I am trying to create a simple program in C that checks for overflows. I need to keep some meta-data when pointers are declared such as the address of the pointer, the size of it (its bounds), etc... This is something I can do with the preprocessor and macros. Problem is I need to call a function when pointers are incremented or dereferenced in order to check if its going out of bounds, a small example:

```
//some code
pointer_name++;
//more code
```

needs to be translated into

```
//some code
pointer++;
checkBounds(pointer_name, starting_address, pointer_size);
//more code
```

In other words I need something that inserts a check at compile time so that it could prevent the overflow at run-time. I am intermediate with C but don't have much experience with compilers. What would be the best way to go about this? If someone could guide me in a certain direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You could check how Valgrind and Clang-asan work. They achieve what you're trying, though I'd say that both systems build on a fairly involved infrastructure system.

Comment: This has been the subject of a good dozen of articles. If you don't have much experience with compilers, then it is unlikely that you will contribute something. Numerous trade-offs have already been tried. http://www.seclab.cs.sunysb.edu/mscc/ https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/sec09/tech/full_papers/akritidis.pdf http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~rob/teaching/cse608-fa05/ccured_popl02.pdf http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety/ …

Comment: This is *fairly* easy to do (for given values of "easy" and "do") if you're willing to give up on the `pointer++` syntax and just use various macros/special functions instead for all your pointer operations. Actually detecting and translating `++` syntax is a much more involved task, most of the effort going into the syntax rather than the meat of checking (although my guess is you could do it easily in C++). If you're writing a new program, is it really important to keep compatibility with classical syntax?

Comment: @Leushenko Yes unfortunately I must keep the classical syntax :/

Comment: @PascalCuoq I am writing this in preparation for a research program I signed up for, so it is mostly for educational purposes, it was known that I had no experience, thanks for the resources though

Comment: Wait, are you asking for compile-time bounds checking, or just insertion of runtime bounds checking operations? The latter is much simpler and [supported out-of-the-box by some compilers](http://bellard.org/tcc/) with no code changes.

Comment: `assert()` is your friend. Don't reinvent it before you mastered it.

Comment: @wildplasser what does assert have to do with it? The question is not about interrupting execution if a condition is false, it is about the metadata that needs to be maintained in order to be able to evaluate the condition. Assert is a rounding error in the quantity if work to reinvent.

Comment: Must you use C? If you switch to C++ and convert your pointers to pointer classes, you can overload the ++ and other such operators to get you your checking. You might first try to compile your C code with a C++ compiler and see how many issues come up (hopefully not many that you can't handle) and then consider how much work it would be to convert your pointers to templatized C++ pointers which would do this checking for you (templatized by type that it points to).

Comment: @DavidNeiss sorry for the late reply, yes I must use C, it is for a research project that tries to make the C language safer. I was kind of hoping there would be an extension/library in the compiler that would let me pick out certain actions (such as pointer/variable increment) and would let me temporarily alter the source code, something like valgrind but in a much smaller scale